# How to have Docker as default engine in Jelastic via manifest?

Tags: docker, paas, jelastic

I use this manifest to deploy one docker (private registry) and a data container to mount some volumes:

```
jpsType: install
name: test create DB1
description: "MariaDB is a database and here it is deployed with DMK"
logo: https://www.dbi-services.com/wp-insides/uploads/2015/04/RGB_dbi_services.png
​
env:
  topology:
    nodes:
    - nodeType: docker
      count: 2
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      flexibleCloudlets: 16
      displayName: mariadbDMK
      image: mariadbjustbin
      registryUrl: node17297-privateregistry.hidora.com
      volumeMounts:
        /u01:
          sourceNodeGroup: storage
        /u02:
          sourceNodeGroup: storage
        /u90:
          sourceNodeGroup: storage

    - nodeType: storage
      displayName: myStorage
```

Here is the problem:
if i go to my environement i can only  scale out the docker already deployed (mariadbdmk) and i cannot add other private dockers (haproxy, etc..)

This is because the manifest put me in a python environment and i dont have access to my private registry.

Anyone has an idea on how to tell the manifest file to put me directly in a docker environment?

Comment: It's not clear with the question. Could you, please expand a bit on the faced issues?

Comment: there is a button with a "+" sign at the bottom to add more images in the same environment 

If you create an environment from non-certified templates (based on custom docker images) - it will always bring you to Docker environment type